# How to create a distance from road raster in QGIS? (Maxent Bias)

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix, maxent

I am trying to create a raster to show the distance from a road for an area in Australia.

I have the Open Street Map data downloaded and converted to a *.SHP file.

Is there a way to produce a raster showing a value relating to the distance to the nearest road?

Comment: Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: @underdark I am not sure where to start. I have searched here and can't find a clear answer. I can find descriptions of calculations for distances from point A via roads but I need to look at each cell in a raster and make it's value equal to the distance to the nearest road. I can't find that here, on the web or in the Qgis documentation. There may be a plugin that does this but I need some assistance identifying such a thing.

Comment: Have a look at https://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/28/qgis-distance-calculator/ found on first page of results: https://www.google.at/search?q=distance+from+road+raster